# How to read from a spinner upon the click of a button android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner

so I have a working spinner that shows four options. Any one of these options needs to be chosen by the user and then they need to click a button at the bottom of the screen that will then alter one of four boolean variables, depending on which option was chosen.

Here's my code so far

```
public class CreateAlarm extends Activity { //declare variables
private Spinner difficultySpinner;
private Button createAlarm;
public static boolean easy = false; //set to true when selected by spinner.
public static boolean medium = false;
public static boolean hard = false;
public static boolean extreme = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_alarm);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_create_alarm, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    difficultySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.difficultySpinner);
    createAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createAlarm);

    createAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

    });
}
```

Could someone help me in telling me how I'd go about getting the value to be taken when the button is pressed? i'm not sure how to read from a spinner and everything I've looked at is just adding to my confusion.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your createAlarm 'onclick()' method:

```
String item=difficultySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```